# Compress/zip a directory using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, zip, selenium-webdriver

I have the following WebDriver Java code for compressing a folder/directory as .zip :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.io.Zip;

public class ZipDir {
    public static void main(String... args){
        Zip zip = new Zip();
        try {
            zip.zip(new File("D:\\TmpFS"), new File("D:\\TmpFS.zip"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code create a "TmpFS.zip" in D drive successfully, but unfortunately the following exception was shown:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP file must have at least one entry
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.finish(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
at com.google.common.io.Closeables.close(Closeables.java:77)
at org.openqa.selenium.io.Zip.zip(Zip.java:90)
at org.openqa.selenium.io.Zip.zip(Zip.java:51)
at packt.selenium.test.chapter6.ZipDir.main(ZipDir.java:11)
```

Good help is appreciable.

Comment: Are there any files existing in directory "D:\\TmpFS" when you try to create zip files?

Comment: There is no existing file(s) on D:\\TmpFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of [Selenuim's Zip](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/io/Zip.java), it seems that it does not add any directory entries to the zip file. It just adds file entries.

For example, if you have the following directory structure:

```
D:\\TmpFS\\Dir1\\file1.txt
D:\\TmpFS\\EmptyDir\\     
D:\\TmpFS\\1.txt
```

it will just add `\\Dir1\\file1.txt` and `1.txt` to the zip file and `EmptyDir` will not be added to the zip file. So, even if you have several folders but none of them have any files, as the code of Zip class, does not add any folders, the output zip file will not have any entry and therefore java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream will throw an error when closing the zip file. So, you should have atleast one file in any of the directory/subdirectories to get a valid zip file.

Comment: Thanks SrikanthLingala. I have now understood that there must exist at least one file on TmpFS folder.

Comment: There is no exception when a file is present on the D:\\TmpFS directory.